# Software to normalize audio on the fly from Blue Yeti mic (for Windows)

Tags: windows, audio, voice

I have a Blue Yeti microphone. It stands on the table, so the volume depends on how close I am to the microphone.

In addition, various programs (telegram, discord, viber etc..) have their own "improvements" for sound.

[image]

Therefore, every time I learn from the interlocutor that I am heard either too loudly or too quietly. It's very tiring for me to have to adjust to each individual program every time. I am looking for a solution to this problem.

It would be nice to have some program, that takes care of the audio processing before that audio gets into the messenger.
Let's call it the EQ, which is halfway between my microphone and the final program.

[image]

Please advise me any free software for Windows, that normalizes audio on the fly

Comment: Did my answer help?

Answer (score 0):

[Logitech G Hub](https://www.logitechg.com/pl-pl/innovation/g-hub.html) is software that utilizes [BLUE VO!CE](https://www.logitechg.com/pl-pl/innovation/blue-voice-technology.html) technology that works with Blue Yeti microphones.

You can change a bunch of paramters there, such as:

- gain
- noise reduction
- equalizer
- volume limiter

etc.